# Why is my second Jinja for loop not working in my HTML table?

Tags: html, html-table, jinja2

{% for Record in Records.Data %}
          {% if Record[3] in lst %}
          
        
        
        
        
        
         
        
        Apply Recommendation
      
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

```
  {% for Record in Records.Data %}
  {% if Record[3] not in lst %}   
      <tr>
    <td><input style="background: transparent" class="w-100" type="text" name="BU" value="{{ Record[0] }}"></td>
    <td><input style="background: transparent" class="w-100" type="text" name="AN" value="{{ Record[1] }}"></td>
    <td id="cn"><input style="background: transparent" class="w-100" type="text" name="CN" value="{{ Record[2] }}" size="30"></td>
    <td><input style="background: transparent" class="w-100" type="text" name="SN" value="{{ Record[3] }}"></td>
    <td><input style="background: transparent" class="w-50" type="text" name="ST" value="{{ Record[4] }}" size="20"></td>
    <td hidden> <input type="text"  name="Rec" value="{{ Record[5] }}"></td>
    <td><input style="background: transparent" class="w-50" type="text" name="COST" value="{{ Record[5] }}" size="20"></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm px-5">Apply Recommendation</button></td>
  </tr>
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

</tbody>
```

I wanted to sort disabled and enabled buttons but it's not happening. the second loop is not at all working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.